# Removing strings from a pandas data series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan, series

I have a complicated pandas series dataframe with a combination of floats, integers and strings. I am trying to remove all the nan from the rows so I can read and manipulate the numbers. The dataframe looks like:

| VAR1 | VAR2 | VAR3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| nan | 14 | 0.0043 |
| nan | 16 | 0.22341 |
| nan | 12 | -0.452 |
| -0.16220 | nan | nan |

I have tried using:  but it does not remove the NaN, and I'm not sure if its because they might be read as a string instead?

```
dataframe = pd.read_pickle(name)
remove_nan = dataframe.dropna
print(remove_nan)
```

`dataframe.drop('NaN')` doesn't work because its embedded in the rows and not an axis.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a simple:

```
df. dropna()
```

Or if your "NaN" is a string perhaps `df.replace("NaN", "0")` will do work

Comment: This doesn't seem to work either. 

remove_nan = dataframe.dropna() returns a completely empty df except for the headers.